# laravel - get a single value from eloquent model to be imported with data as single filed

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model

I have a model called PRODUCT that has one to many relationship with the model REVIEW.
the REVIEW table has a 'rate' column, and I want the average rate from the REVIEW table to be associated with the PRODUCT data when I retrieve all products.
I tried to create a method in the PRODUCT model to call 'rate' in the `::with()` command to do that and that's the code:

```
class Product extends Model{
public function rate(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Review')->select('rate')->avg('rate');
}
```

in controller:

```
return Product::with('rate')->get();
```

but i keep end up with errors..

so is it possible to do that in the model or is there any other way ?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please post any related errors here so we can inspect further. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is mostly better to keep your methods defining relationships as easy as possible.

```
public function reviews(){

    return $this->hasMany('App\Review');
}
```

Now you can use this relation to get the rate. You can do it in different ways :

**1. Adding it as an [appended property](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json) :**

You can add a property which not a column in your model as an appended property.

```
protected $appends = ['rate'];
```

and then have a function to assign the value :

```
public functions getRateAttribute(){

     return $this->reviews->avg('rate') ?? 0;
}
```

The problem with this is, an appended property as the name suggests is always appended to the instance of the model.

So if you  just do following :

```
$product = Product::first();
```

Even if you do not need rate, laravel will still have `$product->rate` ready for you and because of which it will do the average query.

**2. Having it as a method :**

This is the option when you can just create it as a method :

```
public functions getRate(){

     return $this->reviews->avg('rate') ?? 0;
}
```

Advantage of this is, you can use  this when you need. This saves lot of unnecessary queries which an appended property function does even if you don't need it.

This can be then used :

```
$product = Product::first();

// The query fo average will be done below only when you call `getRate` on `$product`

$rate = $product->getRate();
```

I would do it as option 2 if I had a choice.

Also a heads up on Laravel's `avg('column_name)`:

- It gives `null` when no data is present
- It gives value something like `0.0` if you average a non-numeric column
- Gives valid value in format `3.9265` if the value is present which is more than 2 decimal points (mostly 4)

So you can have your function accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
class Product extends Model{

    public function review(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Review');
    }

    public function rate(){
        return $this->review()->avg('rate'); // chain your query here
    }

}
```

then you can access it like:

```
$product = Product::find(1);
dd($product->rate()->get());
```

Answer (score 1):

Laravel uses a lot of magic methods.  You can tap into this with something like this.

```
class Product extends Model{
    public function Reviews(){
        return $this->hasMany(Review::class);
    }
    public functions getRatingAttribute(){
        return $this->Reviews->avg('rate');
    }
}
```

then you can access like this...

```
Product::find(1)->rating;
```

Answer (score 0):

All the above-mentioned solutions lead to N+1 problem. You can try below to achieve eager loading

```
namespace App;
use DB;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

class Product extends Model
{
    public function reviews()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('\App\Review');
    }

    public function ScopeAverageRating(Builder $query){
        return $query->withCount(['reviews as average_rating' => function ($query) {
            $query->select(DB::raw("avg(rate)"));
        }]);
    }

}
```

Then in your controller, you can use App\Product::AverageRating() it will return you collection that can be iterated in view to get average_rating.